# Are there any Valve employees on this site?

Tags: discussion, community

Just wondering if there are any Valve employees who are users on this site who answer technical support questions. I have what seems to be a fairly localized problem with steam and I'm wondering if I can expect to hear a solution from someone with some white-box understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, and even if there were Valve employees here, you would be better off asking your question on the official Steam forums or filing a support ticket directly with Valve.

We are experts in gaming and things related to gaming. We are not expected to be experts on the behind-the-scenes understanding of products as you are requesting. As such, questions that require that kind of knowledge are off topic.

Comment: Okay. But why there is a technical issues tag?

Comment: @phoenixheart6 There is some controversy about the status of that tag. There are a lot of technical issues that are easily solved by gamers, but there are also a lot that require official technical support. We treat them on a one-off basis for now, but there are some who advocate the ban of the class of questions wholesale.

Comment: We demand rigidly defined areas of doubt and uncertainty!